# безусловная пауза

Tags: java, android

Мне необходимо запустить задачу "слушать микрофон", которая должна отработать определенное время в секундах и после этого остановиться. Как правильно организовать эту задержку перед остановкой?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант, можно воспользоваться классом `java.util.Timer`

```
    Timer timer = new Timer(true);
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //выключение микрофона    
        }
    }, TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1));
```

метод `run` в данном примере запустится через 1 день

Answer (score 1):

А можно еще

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){...},1000)
```

А если ты красавчик и используешь RX, то

```
Observable.timer(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
          .subscribe(t -> {...})
```

Comment: Пс... Опечатка!